# Does new energy creation exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe

I know that basic physics states that energy cannot be created or destroyed, but why is that true? For example, one theory called Quantum Fluctuation states that 'normal' and anti energy is constantly being created and then colliding throughout the universe. But experiments at one particle accelerator (I think it was the Large Hadron Collider) showed that when you collide a particle and its anti-energy equivalent, there are more 'positive' emissions that anti-emissions. Wouldn't this mean that energy is constantly being created, since the collisions would create more particle emissions than anti-particle emissions?

Answer (score 1):

If there is evidence of some balance problem that involves energy the missing energy must be somewhere and the extra energy must come from somwhere.

A good way to see this was detailed in the [Fyenman Lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html), where Richard Feyman explained conservation of energy in a very simple way.

So the answer is:

- No, Energy cannot be Created or Destroyed.